# java.io.FileNotFoundException although the file exists, directory appears to be empty

Tags: java, servlets

I am building a Java Web Application and want to trigger a file download. My method in the servlet looks as follows:

```
    public String execute(){
    String viewName = "/Reports.jsp";
    int runID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("run_id"));
    String fileName = "Basic_Report_ID_" + runID + ".csv";
    String filePath = "/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/recvimgpam/" + fileName;
    File reportFile = new File(filePath);
    FileInputStream inputStream;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(reportFile);
        response.setContentType("text/csv");
        response.setContentLength((int) reportFile.length());
        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", fileName);
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;

        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        outStream.close(); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException io){
        io.printStackTrace();
    }


    return viewName;
}
```

I put one report on the server for testing purposes. The directory is the home directory of a second web application "recvimgpam" which generates these reports.

```
swt12@swt12:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/recvimgpam$ ls -l Basic_Report_ID_1.csv
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 207910 Sep 29 00:05 Basic_Report_ID_1.csv
```

Now, when I try to execute the code with run_id = 1, I get the following stacktrace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/recvimgpam/Basic_Report_ID_1.csv (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at commands.DownloadCommand.execute(DownloadCommand.java:35)
    at controller.GetReports.processRequest(GetReports.java:31)
    at controller.GetReports.doPost(GetReports.java:46)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

To do some troubleshooting, I wrote the following to print the directory of my file and - if it does not exist - print the contents of the directory.

```
public class Download{

    public static void main(String[] args){
            String viewName = "/Reports.jsp";
            int runID = 1;
            String fileName = "Basic_Report_ID_" + runID + ".csv";
            String folderPath = "/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/recvimgpam/";
            String filePath = folderPath + fileName;
            File reportFile = new File(filePath);
            try {
                    System.out.println(reportFile.getCanonicalPath());
                    System.out.println(reportFile.getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getMessage();
            }
            if (!reportFile.exists()){
                    System.out.println("File does not exist, listing system directory");
                    File folder = new File(folderPath);
                    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
                    if (listOfFiles != null){
                            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                                    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()){
                                            System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
                                    } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()){
                                            System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
                                    }
                            }
                    } else {
                            System.out.println("No files found in folder");
                    }
            }
            FileInputStream inputStream;
    }
```

}

And all I get is this:

```
swt12@swt12:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ReportPage/WEB-INF/classes/commands$ sudo java Download
/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/recvimgpam/Basic_Report_ID_1.csv
/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/recvimgpam/Basic_Report_ID_1.csv
File does not exist, listing system directory
No files found in folder
```

I truly have no idea why the file is not readable. Is it a permission issue? Would it not give me a different Exception then about permission or access being denied? I'd appreciate any hints!

EDIT: I do not see how the duplicate flag is appropriate. The referenced post is resolved by using an absolute path name which I already do. I also followed the two answers to print the file path as mentioned in the other post but to no avail.

EDIT2: I corrected the code according to @Andreas comment to actually return files in the folderPath than in the filePath which did not make any sense.

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: var/....` - maybe your deployed code is not up to date. (note - no leading slash)

Comment: `listFiles()` returns nothing, since you gave it the full path, incl. file name. Try `folder = new File(filePath).getParentFile()`, or just `folder = reportFile.getParentFile()`, or create a `String folderPath` so you can reuse it.

Comment: check read permission with File.isReadable()

Comment: @Tokazio `No such file or directory` has nothing to do with permissions. If it was a permission problem it would be a different error message.

Comment: have commented on listFiles(). got the permission problem few days ago.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for pointing that out, I fixed it and it did return the correct file list including the Report

Comment: @Tokazio I checked using reportFile.canRead() and it returned true.

Comment: @Scary Wombat I did include the .java files in the .WAR, to make sure I can check it's /var/ with leading slash. Any possibility it loses the dash during deployment or does not overwrite the "old" .class file without leading dash? Thank you.